# Meaning and etymology of "to have a flag day"

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've come across the phrase "to have a flag day." From context it's clear that it's not talking about any kind of celebration of a literal flag, rather, it seems to refer to a synchronization point for a process or community; at a pre-arranged time, everyone agrees to make a coordinated change.

Is this correct? If so, how did it come to mean this?

Comment: Could you tell us the actual context, and what research you have done yourself?

Answer (score 1):

"Flag day" is technical jargon for a major coordinated change. It's usage in this sense refers to a particular instance of such change which took place on June 14, 1966, US Flag Day of that year.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_day_(computing)